# Cleaning a hrefs within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, gsub, code-cleanup

I'm storing a series of a hrefs in an array and I want to clean them so that either just the link is left or so that the apostrophes are taken out. Can anybody help me clean the array in this manner?

The below is one extract from the array to provide an example of what is being stored

```
<a href="http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/B9C7/">View course details on provider's website</a>
```

Could this possibly be done using gsub, if so, how?

Edited to include: 
I've created the array as follows, by scraping data:

```
def process_course_details(course_details)
    details_array =[]
    details_link = true 
    entry_link = true

            details_info = {}
            # Sets all data in hash
            @details_url = course_details.search('div.coursedetails_programmeurl a')
            @details_url.map{ |link| link[/href="([^"]*)"/, 1]} 
            details_info[:url]          = @details_url

            details_array.push(details_info)
            print_details_info(details_info)


         entry_link = course_details.search('ul.details_tabs a').first
         if entry_link

             details_info[:entry] = process_entry(@mechanize.get(entry_link["href"]))
         end 

 end
```

Comment: Can you perhaps post the array and a desired result? Also do you have any attempts to solve it?

Comment: To make sure we understand what you have and what you want, could you post a snippet of the current array (or a part of it) and a snippet with how you'd like the array to look?  It doesn't need to be complete, but seeing an example with 2-3 entries would be helpful.

Comment: The array is huge, it contains several thousand entries. If you have an email address I could send you the code which has comments in it explaining whats happening? I'm creating the array by scraping data from another website and am fairly new to this so not quite sure how to show a proper snippet from the array. I've successfully cleaned one array using gsub, but was unable to do so using the same method for this:     def clean_uniname(text)
     return text.gsub!(/\s|"|'/, '')
    end

Comment: I've edited the question to show the creation of the array which hopefully helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

```
▶ str = %|<a href="http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/B9C7/">View course details on provider's website</a>| # c'mon, SO’s parser
▶ str[/<a.+href="(.*?)"/, 1]
#⇒ "http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/B9C7/"
```

For the array of strings:

```
▶ arr = [str] * 3
▶ arr.map { |s| s[/<a.+href="(.*?)"/, 1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

to parse the entire array:

```
Array(@details_url).map{ |link| link.innert_html[/href="([^"]*)"/, 1] }
```

you can experiment with regular expression on the [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) homepage.

Comment: I've added in: @details_url = course_details.search('div.coursedetails_programmeurl a') in order to be able to call it elsewhere, and as such have added your suggested code to the end of this:
                @details_url.map{ |link| link[/href="([^"]*)"/, 0]}  but I get the following error code: `[]': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError). Do you have any idea what is wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: the first thing is: change the "0" at the end of the bracket into "1", it means 'take the first sub-group of the regex'.

The error you posted hints to that the result of your `.search` command is an array of arrays, instead of an array of strings. of which type is `course_details`? I could not find `.search` method in the standard lib of ruby

Comment: The .search comes from the nokogiri gem I'm using to scrape the data I'm storing in the array. I'm also using mechanize gem. It could possibly be an array of arrays, I'm not entirely sure...I've edited the code at the bottom of the initial question to give you a better look at what I currently have. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, found the methods in question in Nokogiri. As far as I understand the method, it returns objects of the Type Nokogiri::Node. Additionally, if only one is found, it will only return the single node, not a NodeSet.

The first thing you have to make sure is that you always have an array, therefore enclose your result as follows: `Array(@details_url).map...`

Second: you have an array of Nodes now, you will have to parse their inner HTML, instead of themselves, I have updated the code in my answer accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate the help, the code you've provided doesn't seem to remove the apostrophe within the array though, I'm trying to store the array within a database and the apostrophes within each of the entries for @details_url are stopping me from being able to do so. I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it before, sorry. If the code you updated in your post is right, than you haven't assigned the result of `@details.map...` to any variable, therefore, the mapping gets lost before `details_info[:url]          = @details_url`.
You could also use `.map!` instead of `map` which will update `@details_url` in place